# How do I add brackets within a table in Latex?

Tags: tables, brackets

I am trying to get brackets to look like the ones in the picture. I am using the tabulary package currently. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Some code would be nice, just to work from...

Answer (score 3):

Easiest would be to nest a tabular-environment inside \left-\right, like so:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c c c}
X & is & Y \\
$\left.
  \begin{tabular}{c}
    The happening of his\\
    arrival to-morrow
  \end{tabular}\right\}$ 
&
is 
&
$\left\{
  \begin{tabular}{c}
    an event from which it may be\\
     inferred .....
  \end{tabular}\right.$
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Result:
[image: brackets inside tabular]